# How do I merge two layermasks in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I have a document with two layers, each a with a layer mask applied. How do I merge the layer masks from »layer 1« with the layer mask on »layer 2«?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A great answer already here, but I would approach it from a more simple perspective.

1. <kbd>Control</kbd> + *Click* on the first layer mask... loads it as a selection
2. <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + *Click* on the second layer mask *adds* that mask to the selection
3. Hit the button to create a new layer mask

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work if the masks are mostly white. Say you have a small amount of black on the left for the first mask, and a small amount on the right for the second, it doesn't work because the second selection overwrites the first. The only way to do it in this case would be to invert the masks first, copy them, paste the combined mask and then invert it back again.

Answer (score 3):

I use this example for the answer:

- Layer 1 Mask Ellipse
- Layer 2 Mask Square

[image]

- **Menu Image** > **Calculations...**

  - Source 1 – Layer: 1, Channel: Layer Mask
  - Source 2 – Layer: 2, Channel: Layer Mask
  - Blending: Add
  - Result: New Channel

The result is a **new channel** from where you can load the selection and apply it in the layer you need.

[image: Calculation]

If the new mask should be applied to a different layer, choose **New Selection** in the calculation and apply the mask to this layer

[image]

Comment: Plus one as I had never seen the calculations panel before! (I may never see it again haha)